# Simple component in react-chessboard is causing constant "Maximum update depth exceeded" warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chess

I'm trying to render a [chessboard](https://github.com/Clariity/react-chessboard) using the react-chessboard component, but the component appears to be constantly rerendering, when I would expect it to render only once, or upon changes to the chessboard.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Chessboard} from 'react-chessboard';

function ChessCollector() {
  
  const ChessImage = React.memo(({ fen, id }) => {
    return (
      <Chessboard
        position={fen}
        id={id}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {<ChessImage
              fen={'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1'}
              id={'1'}
              />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChessCollector;
```

Running locally, the chessboard renders, but opening the console, I see the following warning continually accruing at the rate of several times per second.

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9973:25
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29:5
    at div
    at ChessOpeningsCollector
```

Using the ReactDevTools profiler, the component is constantly rerendering, but it's unclear why to me. I'm not using setState inside useEffect (in my code at least) in this particular example, so the guidance from the warning message was not helpful.

I have reproduced the issue in a simple example (from a more complex application), to confirm there were no interactions with any other components causing this. Other questions with the same error have not been fruitful in debugging this particular example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue probably lies in the `react-chessboard` library itself. I just checked their index page.
`https://github.com/Clariity/react-chessboard/blob/main/src/chessboard/index.tsx` is the file from the which the component is being exported.
I just found this that could be causing maximum re-render issue,
so basically in line 44 `metrics` variable is calculated with the help of `getBoundingClientRect` method which returns an object containing x, y, top, bottom, left, right, width, height properties. This `metrics` variable is used as a dependency to the `useEffect` slightly below in line 51. A state `setBoardContainerPos` is being set inside this `useEffect` in line 47 which causes re-render because of which `metrics` is calculated again and `useEffect` runs again. Since `metrics` is an object which is given as a dependency, previous metrics is not as same as the current even when the property values are same.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed in 4.3.1.

https://github.com/Clariity/react-chessboard/releases/tag/v4.3.1